# Getting road distance between two points using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to put in a latitude and longitude for 2 points and then get the road distance between them.

Is that possible using Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 2):

Earth Engine does not offer an algorithm for finding routes along roads.

The closest related feature that does exist is the [cumulativeCost](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_cumulative_cost) algorithm, but that is an image-space algorithm that will not be efficient for computing a path between only two points.